# POST request with JSON in R giving bad request

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to integrate an API into my R script to format indentation in SQL queries. I'm somehow getting a 400 bad response.

```
uri <- "https://sqlformat.org/api/v1/format"
test3 <- "{'sql': 'Select * from foo where blabla', 'reindent': 1}"
result <- POST(url = uri, body = test3, encode = "json", verbose())
```

The API is delivered by https://sqlformat.org/api/. Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's something on server side? If I try to use `POST` with `Postman/R`, it fails.

If I try it with `GET` from `R` it works fine

```
> uri="https://sqlformat.org/"
> GET(url=uri, path="api/v1/format", query=URLencode("reindent=1&sql=select * from foo"))
> str(content(response))
str(content(response))
List of 1
 $ result: chr "select *\nfrom foo"
```

Comment: Yeah might be some other strange issue. I will use your GET solution then - thank you so much!